# Differences between pronouncing the 'G' and 'J' in US/British English

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english, letters-of-the-alphabet

I'm currently pronouncing:

- **g** as /**dgi**/
- **j** as /**djay**/

I'm not sure if this is the American or Britisch way to pronounce it.

If it depends on the choice of words, I was just singing the alphabet.
**Question**: I was wondering what is the correct way of pronouncing these letters in American English and British English?

**EDIT**: I don't need to know the difference in a context of a sentence or a word. Just the difference while singing the alphabet in American English and British English.

Comment: I sing **g** as /jee/ and **j** as /jey/ or /jei/.

Comment: Do you just mean when reciting the alphabet, or in the context of words?  Because the specific word can make a big difference in the pronunciation of **g** and **j**.

Comment: @stangdon just as I mentioned, like while singing the alphabet.

Comment: Oxford learner's dictionary can help with both AmE and BrE pronunciations of letters, for example, http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/pronunciation/english/g_1

Comment: I occasionally hear ***gibber*** pronounced with a "hard" ***g*** (i,e. - ***/ˈɡɪbə/*** rather than ***/ˈdʒɪbə/***), but I don't know if this (or any similar) represents regional variation such as AmE/BrE. OP's ***/dgi/*** and ***/djay/*** simply don't correspond to anything familiar to me (they're not valid IPA anyway).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The letter G  is called /dʒi:/ in both British and American English. It rhymes with *see*.

The letter J is called /dʒeɪ/ in in both British and American English. It rhymes with *say*.

Answer (score 5):

In The Cambridge Encyclopedia of The English Language, David Crystal notes 'no important regional variation' in the pronunciation of 'j' (dz) as a consonant. But there are regional variations in the 'ee' and especially in the 'ay'. (I am Australian and might *say* (but not sing) closer to 'jay-ee'.)

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference in the names or pronunciations of the letters G and J in any English dialect. They are called "Jee" and "Jay" respectively (with the consonant pronounced like a combination of "d" and the French "j").

There are notable differences in other letters: Z is called "Zed" in most of the English-speaking countries, but "Zee" in the US; and the name of the letter H is usually pronounced "Eitch", but in some UK regions it is distinctly pronounced "Heitch".

Comment: I don't think French has the /dʒ/ that we use at the beginning of /dʒi:/ or /dʒeɪ/ does it? It only has the /ʒ/ sound that we hear in words like *jamais*, doesn't it?

Comment: @Araucaria: when French /d/ (represented by "d") is followed by French /ʒ/ (represented by "j"), we get the same sound as English /dʒ/, more or less. In French, "dj" mainly occurs in loanwords such as "djinn."

Comment: @sumelic So the word *djinn* is pronounced with a /dʒ/ not a /ʒ/?

Comment: @Araucaria: Yes. I only know of "dj" occurring in loanwords from Arabic, but I think the sound is used in some loanwords from English as well.

Comment: I must have been having a brainstorm when I commentd before. Your categorical answer here is categorically wrong!  In Scottish English J is most often pronounced /dʒaɪ/, rhymes with *pie*. As noted by Michael below.

Comment: It is the same name for the letter, with a difference in pronunciation. It is a noteworthy exception.

Answer (score 3):

Many Scottish people pronounce j 'jye' (to rhyme with eye, fly, sigh etc). Can make a telephone conversation tricky if they are spelling something.

Answer (score 1):

there is a rule:

It states any "g" followed by i,e,or y  might say 'j'

eg: gym. gel, giant.

Although the stated rule holds good in most cases, there are a lot of exceptions and unfortunately some of those exceptions happen to be common words; "get" and "give" are two examples. "Margarine", "gaol" and "gynaecologist" also break the rule.

Sometimes, if we don't want "g" to say "j", we add a "u". We don't usually pronounce it, it's just there to keep the "g" hard: "disguise", "guest" and "vague" are examples of this.

Comment: That rule would be better stated as: _'g' followed by i, e, or y **might say** 'j'_, because it's really pointing out that we use the "hard g" when the 'g' is followed by 'a' or 'o'.

Comment: But is there a difference in pronouncing it in US or Britisch english when singing the alphabet? I didn't ask about how to pronounce it in a context ( of a word), only purely in the alphabet and if there is a difference between US or Britisch pronuciation.

Comment: I am not a native speaker.But I can say that  I didn't realize any serious differences unless you want to make petty distinctions.So I recommend not wasting time splitting hairs.

Answer (score 1):

> But is there a difference in pronouncing it in US or Britisch english
> when singing the alphabet? I didn't ask about how to pronounce it in a
> context ( of a word), only purely in the alphabet and if there is a
> difference between US or Britisch pronuciation.

There is no difference. When you say 'singing' the alphabet, do you mean you sing it like a song? To a tune? If you just **say** the letters, as most people do, then you are **reciting** the alphabet.